# How to add style to category link?

Tags: categories

```
<h1><?php the_category(' &bull; '); ?> » <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="my-title-class"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

How to add `class="my-category-class"` to the links, produces by `the_category` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `the_category` filter to hook a callback function like this:

```
add_filter('the_category','add_class_to_category',10,3);

function add_class_to_category( $thelist, $separator, $parents){
    $class_to_add = 'my-category-class';
    return str_replace('<a href="', '<a class="' . $class_to_add . '" href="', $thelist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick your choice:

- style categories by already existing CSS definition: `.post-categories a {YOUR_STYLE_HERE}`;
- use jQuery to add your class: `$("link-categories a").addClass("my-category-class");`;
- write your own function to echo categories with your own classes/attributes.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner I would try creating my function, that I would call instead of the_category();

```
function my_category_func($sep, $classname)
    {
        $output = null;
        $output = '<div class="$classname">'.the_category( $sep ).'</div>';
        return $output;
    }
```

I believe this could be done more professionally, including all the variables, but I'd go this way for starters ;)